# Bufferedreader explanation?

Tags: java

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

`System.in(Standard input stream)-` gets the input from keyboard in bytes

`InputStreamReader:` Converts the bytes into Unicode characters/ converts the standard input into reader object to be used with BufferedReader

`Finally BufferedReader`: Used to read from character input stream(Input stream reader)

`String c = br.ReadLine();` -- a method used to read characters from input stream and put them in the string in one go not byte by byte.

Is everything above right ? Please correct if anything wrong !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nearly there, but this:

> `String c = br.readLine();` -- a method used to read characters from input stream and put them in the string in one go not byte by byte.

It reads characters from the input *reader* (`BufferedReader` doesn't know about streams) and returns a whole line in one go, not *character by character*. Think of it in layers, and "above" the `InputStreamReader` layer, the concept of "bytes" doesn't exist any more.

Also, note that you can read blocks of characters with a `Reader` without reading a line: `read(char[], int, int)` - the point of `readLine()` is that it will do the line ending detection for you.

(As noted in comments, it's also `readLine`, not `ReadLine` :)

Comment: But then if someone asks what is  the purpose of BufferedReader in the statement, am i not supposed to say that it reads character from input stream reader ?

Comment: @rd4code: It's not clear what you mean by "the purpose of BufferedReader" - in this case you're using `BufferedReader` for the `readLine()` method it provides, which isn't available on `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: @rd4code: That gives you an `InputStreamReader` from which you can read characters obtained from `System.in`. But you can't use `readLine` on that.

Comment: kkk. thats why we wrap the bufferedreader class around inputstreamreader so to perform the readLine Function

Answer (score 0):

## What is the purpose of BufferedReader, explanation?

Bufferedreader is a java class, the following is the hierarchy of this class.

**java.lang.Object ==> java.io.Reader ==> java.io.BufferedReader**

Also, BufferedReader provides an efficient way to read content. Very Simple..
Let's have a look at the following example to understand.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader contentReader = null;
        int total = 0; // variable total hold the number that we will add

        //Create instance of class BufferedReader
        //FileReader is built in class that takes care of the details of reading content from a file
        //BufferedReader is something that adds some buffering on top of that to make reading fom a file more efficient.
        try{
            contentReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\\Numbers.txt"));
            String line = null;

            while((line = contentReader.readLine()) != null)

                total += Integer.valueOf(line);

            System.out.println("Total: " + total);
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        finally{
            try{
                if(contentReader != null)
                    contentReader.close();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }



    }
}
```