# Understanding BufferedReader and InputStreamReader

Tags: java, server

I am having trouble understanding what this line does exactly in terms of server side stuff.

`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`

I have read other S.O threads but I am still having trouble understanding simply what that line does.

I am very confident in C if anyone would like give an analogy with C code, thanks.

Comment: Try the [Basic I/O](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html) section of the Java Tutorials.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this question is a [duplicate of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10547362).  I think probably not, since you're coming at it from a slightly different angle.  It might help you though, to read Jon Skeet's excellent answer on that question.  (Generally speaking, reading answers by Jon Skeet is helpful).

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Yo, that answered all my questions! Thanks a lot <3

Answer (score -2):

`System.in` is the standard input.

`InputStreamReader` allows you to associate a stream that reads from the specified input (in this case the standard input), so now we have a stream.

`BufferedReader` is an "abstraction" to help you to work with streams. For example, it implements `readLine` instead of reading character by character until you find a '\n' to get the whole line. It just returns a String after this proccess.

In C, there are no "strings" you have to use a character array, but you can read data in to a character array from stdin with something like:

```
char input[100];
...
scanf("%99[^\n]", input);
```

or

```
fgets (input, 100 , stdin)
```

In C++, you'd use:

```
using namespace std;

string line;
getline(cin, line);
```

**BufferedReader**

Read text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines. The buffer size may be specified, or the default size may be used. The default is large enough for most purposes. In general, each read request made of a Reader causes a corresponding read request to be made of the underlying character or byte stream. It is therefore advisable to wrap a BufferedReader around any Reader whose read() operations may be costly, such as FileReaders and InputStreamReaders.

**BufferedReader#readLine()**

Read a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

**InputStreamReader**

An InputStreamReader is a bridge from byte streams to character streams: It reads bytes and decodes them into characters using a specified charset. The charset that it uses may be specified by name or may be given explicitly, or the platform's default charset may be accepted. Each invocation of one of an InputStreamReader's read() methods may cause one or more bytes to be read from the underlying byte-input stream. To enable the efficient conversion of bytes to characters, more bytes may be read ahead from the underlying stream than are necessary to satisfy the current read operation.

**System**

The System class contains several useful class fields and methods. It cannot be instantiated.

Among the facilities provided by the System class are standard input, standard output, and error output streams; access to externally defined "properties"; a means of loading files and libraries; and a utility method for quickly copying a portion of an array.

**System.in**

The "standard" input stream. This stream is already open and ready to supply input data. Typically this stream corresponds to keyboard input or another input source specified by the host environment or user.

[See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547362/bufferedreader-explanation)

Comment: A lot of this answer seems to be copy-pasted from Oracle's published Javadoc.  It would be really good if you acknowledged your source.  If you don't, some people might consider this plagiarism.

Comment: `InputStreamReader` is not a stream. `BufferedReader` is not an abstraction.